# A smaller modulus-to-noise ratio means more security in LWE

Tags: lwe, gaussian-noise, advantage

Let $\text{Adv}^{\text{DLWE}}_{n,m,q,\sigma}$ be the advantage of an attacker to distinguish LWE samples from uniform ones, where $m$ is the number of samples, $q$ the modulus and $\sigma$ the standard deviation of the error distribution.

I can't find an explicit expression for this advantage.

Does reducing $q$ and increasing $\sigma$ implies smaller advantage (and hence better security?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find an explicit expression for this advantage.

There isn't one.
This is because it is consistent with the state of the art of complexity theory that $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$, and therefore $\mathsf{Adv}_{n,m,q,\sigma}^{\mathsf{DLWE}}$ is some polynomial in the sizes of the relevant parameters.
It is *also* consistent with current cryptographic thought that this isn't the case, and that more aggressive things are true, namely that $\mathsf{Adv}^{\mathsf{DLWE}}_{n,m,q,\sigma}$ is almost entirely controlled by $n\log q$, and in particular:

1. $m$ can be quite large without impacting security, and
2. $\sigma$ can be quite small (theoretically $\sigma = \Omega(\sqrt{n})$ is generally required, although practically $\sigma = O(1) \approx 8$ is common).

So how does one concretely evaluate this advantage? Generally by (concretely) evaluating the state-of-the-art of known attacks.
To this end, there are two main resources:

1. The ``LWE Estimator'' of Albrecth et al. is incredibly popular. You can see the initial paper [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/046.pdf), and the (more up to date) sage module [here](https://lwe-estimator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
2. Existing concrete proposals of lattice-based primitives. For example, NIST PQC finalists Kyber, Saber, and NTRUPrime all include (concrete) analysis justifying their parameter choices. For heavier primitives, the [Homomorphic Encryption Standard](https://homomorphicencryption.org/standard/) contains tables of suggested parameters, as well as summaries of attacks that guided the constructions of these tables.

That all being said...

> Does reducing $q$ and increasing $\sigma$ implies smaller advantage (and hence better security?)

All else being equal, the answer is yes.
Given an LWE instance $(\mathbf{A}, \vec b)$, one can modulus switch from $q\mapsto q'$ (for $q' < q$, the analysis is cleaner if $q' \mid q$ though).
This roughly maps the standard deviation of the error from $\sigma \mapsto \frac{q'}{q}\sigma < \sigma$.
One could then increase this error to some standard deviation $\sigma' > \sigma > \frac{q'}{q}\sigma$ by adding an appropriate Gaussian.

This is to say that there is a relatively simple reduction from $\mathsf{DLWE}_{n, m, q, \sigma}\leq \mathsf{DLWE}_{n, m, q', \sigma'}$ for $\sigma' > \sigma$ and $q' \mid q$ (the case of $q' < q$ is not much harder, but you have to deal with some "rounding error"), so the advantage will be smaller.

Comment: Thank you @Mark. Is there any paper where I can find a reduction between DLWE for different parameters?

Comment: They are spread between a few papers. The two fundamental ideas are that, given a (fixed) number of LWE samples, one can generate more (of slightly larger error) cheaply. This justifies the bound $m$ not impacting $\mathsf{Adv}$ much. See section 5 of [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/337.pdf) for some details (the result is from before this paper though). The other main one is the analysis of modulus switching, in [this](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lwehard-old.pdf).